# Using DateIntervalType class in form

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

How to implement new `DateIntervalType` field in Symfony project?

```
$builder->add('remindEvery', DateIntervalType::class, array(
    'widget'      => 'integer', // render a text field for each part
    // 'input'    => 'string',  // if you want the field to return a ISO 8601 string back to you

    // customize which text boxes are shown
    'with_years'  => false,
    'with_months' => false,
    'with_days'   => true,
    'with_hours'  => true,
));
```

The DateIntervalType field type was introduced in Symfony 3.2. 
This field allows the user to select an interval of time. For example, if you want to allow the user to choose how often they receive a status email, they could use this field to choose intervals like every "10 minutes" or "3 days".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create field in entity WorkingTime:

```
class WorkingTime
{
   /**
   * @var int
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
   private $id;

  /**
  * @var string
  *
  * @ORM\Column(
  *     name="duration_task", type="string", length=25
  * )
  */
 private $durationTask;

// ...more fields

 /**
 * ##################################################
 * Getter & Setter
 * ##################################################
 */


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Get durationTask
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDurationTask()
{
    return $this->durationTask;
}

/**
 * Set durationTask
 *
 * @param string $durationTask
 *
 * @return WorkingTime
 */
public function setDurationTask( $durationTask )
{
    $this->durationTask = $durationTask;

    return $this;
}

// ...
```

in Controller:

```
$newWorkingTime = new WorkingTime();

// you can set default duration: 0 hour 1 minute 
$newWorkingTime
        ->setDurationZz( 'PT0H1M' );

$form = $this->createForm( WorkingTimeType::class, $newWorkingTime );
$form->handleRequest( $request )->getData( $newWorkingTime );

// save to database
if ( $form->isSubmitted() ) {
        $em2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em2->persist( $newWorkingTime );
        $em2->flush();
}

return $this->render(
        'AppBundle:WorkingTime:new.html.twig', [
              'form'     =>     $form->createView(),
        ]                                         ]
    );
```

class WorkingTimeType:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateIntervalType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;


/**
 * Class WorkingTimeType
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Form
 */
class WorkingTimeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
    {
        $builder
            ->add( 'durationTask', DateIntervalType::class, [
                                   'input'        => 'string',
                                   'widget'       => 'choice',
                                   // choice fields to display
                                   'with_years'   => false,
                                   'with_months'  => false,
                                   'with_days'    => false,
                                   'with_minutes' => true,
                                   'with_hours'   => true,
                                   'with_seconds' => false,
                               ]
            )
            ->add( 'save', SubmitType::class );
    }


    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions( OptionsResolver $resolver )
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults( [ 'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\WorkingTime' ] );

    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'success_form';
    }
}
```

in new.html.twig:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```